# Nagios - Interface IP Check Script

Tags: linux, interface, ip, snmp, nagios

I'm a bit of a novice with Linux & Nagios plugins but I need to setup alerts for when router interfaces loses their IP's (so when it is seen as 0.0.0.0). I did a little research of other peoples scripts and wrote the below script named check_ip.pl:

```
$snmpIfIP = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.23695.2.1.3.1.1.3.0.0';
$noip = "0.0.0.0";
if ($snmpIfIP != $noip) {
echo "Interface has an IP";
exit 0 } else { echo "No IP on Interface"; exit 2 }
```

In Nagios, I then assigned this to a check_command: $USER1$/check_ip.pl

Assigned a template to use this check command and created a service from this template. SNMP between the Nagios server and the Router is working - However i'm getting "(Return code of 126 is out of bounds - plugin may not be executable)" - so i've done something wrong with the plugin code!

I know the following is correct:

- OID to pull the IP of the interface is correct (tested this)
- The IP on the router is 0.0.0.0 so, it does match for the expected argument

Can anyone offer advice / how the plugin file needs to be written please?

Many Thanks.

Comment: `ls -l /path/to/ProblemPlugin` May you need to then `chmod +x /path/to/ProblemPlugin`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your plugin actually in the `$USER1$` directory? `$USER1$` is `/usr/local/nagios/libexec` in most cases.

You'll need to make sure that not only is your plugin executable:

`chmod +x /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ip.pl`

But also that it is executable (and owned) by the Nagios user:

`chown nagios:nagios /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ip.pl`

If you've tested your script and it's working properly when ran manually, then this should resolve your issue!

However, the code you posted isn't a full plugin. What I see won't return what you're looking for. Is there something specifically you need help with regarding the code?

Also, make sure you check out the [Nagios Plugin Development Guidelines](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html)!